How to change the super user account in the authentication required dialog?
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 but whenever I want to install something from the App Center a dialog box pops up saying "Authentication Required" and asks me for the password. However the password for the account it's asking for is not my account but the first user. How do I change the account it's asking for to my account?
I have checked and my account is part of the sudoers group
$ groups $USER
<myname> : <myname> sudo <bunch of other groups>...

I've also tried giving myself admin rights through sudo visudo and adding a custom.conf file in /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d
Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:<myname>
Action=*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

I have also tried re-logging in and rebooting the computer.
